# How to modify a DocX file and save to a different location with OpenXML SDK?

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I want to use OpenXML SDK 2.0 to do the following:

1. Open A.docx
2. Modify the document
3. Save the modified document as B.docx

A & B would be parameters to a method and they could be the same. Assuming they are not the same, A should not be modified at all.

I cannot see a "SaveAs" method, in fact `WordprocessingDocument" class doesn't really seem to support concept of file location.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a memory stream and pass it to the `WordprocessingDocument.Open` method. After I'm done changing the document, I just write the bytes to the destination:

```
var source = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    ms.Write(source, 0, source.Length);
    /* settings defined elsewhere */
    using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(ms, true, settings)) {
        /* do something to the doc */
    }
    /* used in File.WriteAllBytes elsewhere */
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 on the answer already given...

Here is an MSDN article that discusses working with in-memory Open XML documents.  I think that you will find it relevant.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee945362.aspx